# AMD gpu pro driver not working in ubuntu with linux 4.13, causes black screen (but works with 4.10)

Tags: boot, drivers, amdgpu-pro

I'm no expert at Linux/Ubuntu, so kind of lost and would appreciate the assistance.

When my Linux was upgraded to 4.13 from 4.10, my screen would turn black right after the Ubuntu selection in the boot menu (I have windows and Ubuntu dual boot). I couldn't get it to work until I selected the "Advanced options for Ubuntu" in the grub menu and selected to boot with Linux 4.10.

Later I thought I would attempt to uninstall the amd gpu driver, since I saw somewhere that that might be the issue, and booting into 4.13 worked but was extremely laggy.

I know there are some answers around that say if you have this issue then your card isn't supported by this driver, but it worked fine for a while, only the 4.13 update made it not work. My card is the R9 290.

I also tried the various solutions posted about a black screen issue, including setting the nomodeset option.

If anyone knows a solution for this please let me know, thank you!

Comment: Same issue for me. Someone filed a bug in Launchpad

Comment: Glad I'm not the only one. Do you have a link to it by any chance, so that I can follow any updates on it?

Comment: https://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=article&item=linux-413-gcn101&num=1 Does this help?

Comment: Thanks, but I just saved myself the trouble and am using the Mesa drivers instead, since they work flawlessly